# Where does this alternative form of Faraday's law come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, notation, electromagnetic-induction

In the Sears-Zemansky physics book on page 1007, there is an alternative way to express Faraday's law for a moving conductor in a magnetic field:
$$d\mathcal E =\left(\vec v \times \vec B\right)\cdot d\vec l$$

Where does this expression come from?

Comment: Search term *"motional EMF"*. This is—perhaps—better thought of as a precursor to Faraday's law.

Comment: I already did, but didn't found anything related to this specific formula.

Comment: The usual introductory treatments the make simplifying assumptions that all the interesting angles in the system are right angles. The vector products you see in that expression take care of the cases where the angles are not necessarily right.